# Bootstrap acting as mobile from 980px - 1200px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've recently began using Bootstrap and have not had any problems doing so except for this one issue I've run into. I've set up my own personal website using it and styled it to be responsive and so far it looks great on everything.

But the problem I am having is that from 980px - 1200px, Bootstrap renders the page in full-page rows (exactly as it does as if it were on mobile). I'm using bootstrap-responsive.min My page set up is:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3"> <!-- sidebar here --> </div>
      <div class="span8"> <!-- content of each page --> </div>
      <div class="span1"> &nbsp; <!-- empty for spacing --> </div>
 </div>
```

980px-1200px is the only interval for which it renders correctly, and I so far have no media queries for that interval. Has anyone run in to this problem before? Or does anyone know what might be causing this?

A page example can be seen here (you will notice if you slowly resize the browser window):
http://portfolio.jrstrauss.net/work/

Answer (score 1):

You have a media query targeting screen widths up to 979px,

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)
```

And the next one is targeting screen widths of 1200px and up

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
```

anything in-between 980px and 1200px will be using the default styles. You can fix this by changing the 2nd media query to have a min-width: 980px instead of 1200px.

Comment: This functionality is baked into bootstrap-responsive.css for some reason. I don't understand why. But this fix works!

Answer (score 0):

[edit] It's something completely different: You need to rewrite/fix your HTML, e.g. you can apply `.span3` to the `header` element, so it floats as intended. The same goes for your second block.

```
<header class="row-fluid" style="display: inline-block;">
    <nav class="main span3">
        …
    </nav>
</header>
```

You basically did set the correct classes, but then added full-width block elements inside.